# Diagnosing Sonarqube with Roslyn analyzers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, sonarqube5.3

I am setting up Sonarqube for my team and have run into issues working with [the Sonarqube Roslyn SDK found on github](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonarqube-roslyn-sdk).

Following the instructions on the github page, I have successfully compiled the solution.  However, when running the generator tool at [directory]/Sonarqube.Plugins.Roslyn.PluginGenerator.exe, I am getting the following error when attempting to create a plugin per the instructions for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers:

```
c:\users\[HomeDirectory]\src\github\sonarqube-roslyn-sdk\RoslynPluginGenerator\bin\Debug\sonarqube.plugins.roslyn.plugingenerator.exe /a:c:\users\[HomeDirectory]\src\github\sonarqube-roslyn-sdk\RoslynPluginGenerator\bin\Debug\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers:1.0.0
Roslyn Analyzer Plugin Generator for SonarQube 0.1.0.0
    [DEBUG] Parsed NuGet reference. Id: c:\users\[HomeDirectory]\src\github\sonarqube-roslyn-sdk\RoslynPluginGenerator\bin\Debug\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, version: 1.0.0
    [DEBUG] Fetching NuGet config files...
    [DEBUG] Enabled package sources:
    [WARNING] No enabled package sources. Please update the NuGet config to specify at least one valid package source.
    Attempting to locate package with id 'c:\users\[HomeDirectory]\src\github\sonarqube-roslyn-sdk\RoslynPluginGenerator\bin\Debug\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers'
    [DEBUG] Number of packages located: 0
    No packages with the specified id were found:
    c:\users\[HomeDirectory]\src\github\sonarqube-roslyn-sdk\RoslynPluginGenerator\bin\Debug\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers
```

I haven't had other issues with NuGet within Visual Studio with the proper (v3) package source enabled on the machine.  I understand the Sonarqube Roslyn SDK is a beta at this point, but was wondering if anyone out there was actually successful creating a plug-in off a referenced NuGet library.

As a side note, Sonarqube is working great except that I haven't been able to get analyzer based static analysis issues into Sonarqube.  This issue is specific to the SDK.  Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed with the Roslyn SDK after posting of the original question.  Simply follow the instructions as provided on the SDK's github page.